# Change the date and month only in POSIXct format?

Tags: r, date

I ran analysis yesterday and have dates in one data.frame as follows:

`$ Start    : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-30 00:00:00" "2017-04-30 00:09:39" "2017-04-30 00:00:00" "2017-04-30 00:08:42" ...`

However, I am working on analysis today and trying to lookup a median time within the date range of a data.frame. The dates in this data.frame are today's date:

`$ MedianR: POSIXct, format: "2017-05-01 00:00:08" "2017-05-01 00:01:09" "2017-05-01 00:01:33" "2017-05-01 00:01:51" ...`

Is it possible to edit the date and month only, in either data.frame, so they are the same?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want. The month is part of the date. You could modify the date in a POSIXct in several ways as you will find here in SO. 1- basic algebra with lubridate e.g. df - 30. 2- using format() & paste() , etc. Would be great if you show your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract out parts of the date you can use:

```
dataframe$dateonly <- ymd(strptime(as.character(dataframe$datetime), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

you could pull that out or you can also pull out year month and day using lubridate

```
dataframe$year <- year(dataframe$date)
```

and do this for month and day and whatever else and then paste them back together to make a new date if that makes any sense at all?